# Pyspark shell outputs several numbers instead of the loading arrow

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am currently fitting a [Support Vector Machine](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=svm#pyspark.mllib.classification.SVMWithSGD) model for some training data with `104` boolean features, for so I use a `SparseVector` as features, e.g. (I show it as a `DataFrame` just for readability but it's in fact an `RDD`):

```
+--------------------+-----+
|            features|label|
+--------------------+-----+
|(104,[11,44,76,96...|  0.0|
|(104,[11,47,60,96...|  1.0|
|(104,[14,47,60,96...|  0.0|
|(104,[4,44,72,96]...|  1.0|
+--------------------+-----+
```

The problem I have is that the `SparkShell` shows millions and millions of numbers (e.g. below), I assume that this printing will slow down the performance of the application, so how do I turn off this? and what is producing this?

```
0 104
1 104
2 104
3 104
0 104
1 104
2 104
3 104
0 104
1 104
2 104
3 104
0 104
1 104
2 104
3 104
0 104
[Stage 494:========>                                               (5 + 4) / 32]
```

Actually the loading arrow is showed at the end of the process. Besides, this happens with other models like `LogisticRegression`

Comment: This is to weird, I can't replicate it outside of my notebook :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these 3 lines in your pyspark shell:

```
logger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
logger.LogManager.getLogger("org"). setLevel( logger.Level.ERROR )
logger.LogManager.getLogger("akka").setLevel( logger.Level.ERROR )
```

Where ERROR might be WARN if you prefer a bit more output

Comment: Nope, this is not my problem and my current log4j.properties looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/Bonsanto/c487624db805f56882b8)

Comment: It's a strange one, I know its a stupid question, but are you certain there's no extra print statements hidden in the code?

Comment: I am currently using jupyter for the notebooks, and they don't print anything, the problem is in the spark-shell it shows millions and millions of numbers! [Take a look](http://i.imgur.com/mohLnwr.png)

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @desertnaut Thanks for your interest, I am trying to make a simple example, I will finish it tomorrow!